# Validation called on ActiveRecord association when linking some existing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

In my Rails 3.2 application, I have three ActiveRecord models, Post PostTag and Tag. PostTag is a link table (only contains foreign keys to the others).

There are several existing Tag records. I manually assign a collection of Tag records to Post as follows in my posts_controller.create method:

```
tags = Tag.all
@post.tags = tags
```

When I save, it runs my custom validation method in Tag as if it were creating new Tag records, even though I am simply linking Tag records to the new Post. I also have no validates_associated declared in Post. Models:

```
Post:
has_many :tags, :through => :post_tags
has_many :post_tags

PostTag:
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :tag

Tag:
has_many :posts, :through => :post_tags
has_many :post_tags

validate :validate_something

def validate_something
  ...
end
```

I have tried using << instead of = in the assignment above as per [the ActiveRecord documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many), but no luck.

Comment: please post some understandable code and what you mean exactly, for me its not clear what you are asking

Comment: hopefully it is clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you encounter this problem since your association is `:through => :post_tags`. You need to create new `PostTag` elements to keep the links. Try this:

```
Tag.all.each { |tag| PostTag.create!(tag: tag, post: @post) }
```

Alternatively, you can try to port to [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many) association, which abstracts `PostTag` away.

Comment: Well, assuming the validation passes, the links are created just fine.  Makes no sense that the validation is being called. Your solutions indeed work around the problem, thanks.